# Meaning of "Hakatan"

Tags: names

What is the significance of the word "Hakatan" after one's surname?  If this descriptive is used by learned people and rabbonim, then is it not self-defeating to call oneself "Hakatan"?

Comment: Please give some examples.

Comment: Some people write this out of modesty, "me the small/modest Reb X etc."

Comment: R' Menashe Klein signed his name as "Menashe hakatan", which is a play on his surname

Answer (score 7):

The [Talmud Yerushalmi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerusalem_Talmud) (Sotah 9:13) asks why [Shmuel Hakatan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shmuel_ha-Katan) was called "Hakatan", and it provides two explanations:

> ולמה נקרא שמו קטן לפי שהוא מקטין עצמו ויש אומרים לפי שמעט היה קטן משמואל הרמתי
>
> And why was his name called "katan" (small)? Because he diminished himself. And some say because he was slightly lesser than [Shmuel Haramati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel).